# Correct approach to solve with SQL Server Sum

Tags: sql-server

I am running through a problem for knowing if a number is available.

For example I am having a table that stores the transactions, if the transactions is outgoing we stored the number with negative quantity and if its incomming then we store as positive quanitity.

In the begining I thought the SUM would be enough to find the available if the quantity is greater than ZERO but it wont be correct because based on the second example data you can see that 'Bike-Serial_001' was not available at the start then at later stage it was available.

How can I write a SQL query and `SUM` function to solve this issue?

```
ID                                          Number              Quantity            syscreated
F7F405B4-CE7E-431B-BAC1-3AC78F436D37    Bike-Serial_001             -1          25-02-2015 12:05:19
279ABB0A-195E-48CB-8443-E5F8E1FCBA38    Bike-Serial_001             1           25-02-2015 12:05:56
25A56A3F-A225-4BBB-B458-9D2CCE3F130D    Bike-Serial_001             1           25-02-2015 12:06:08
EC0C0A4E-651D-4CCD-AFEF-547F973B3243    Bike-Serial_001             -1          25-02-2015 12:07:37
9034E016-19C0-4F3A-A4C6-B84F29D05912    Bike-Serial_001             1           25-02-2015 12:08:14

Another Example in which simple SUM will not be appropriate.

ID                                          Number              Quantity            syscreated
F7F405B4-CE7E-431B-BAC1-3AC78F436D37    Bike-Serial_001             -1          25-02-2015 12:05:19
279ABB0A-195E-48CB-8443-E5F8E1FCBA38    Bike-Serial_001             1           25-02-2015 12:05:56
```

Comment: If you have a datetime column, why not use that to find the most recent instance of your number?

Comment: It's unclear why `SUM(Quantity) ... GROUP BY Number` wouldn't meet your needs.

Comment: SUM(Quanity) will make s1 SUM to be ZERO and also unavailable. But as you can see it should be available becasue the last transaction was incomming.

Comment: How do you know which transaction was last incomming? Is there a column we don't see? What is the ordering based on?

Comment: table has datetime column, consider the example data as ordered by datetime.

Comment: Can you add this datetime column to your sample dataset?

Comment: How many bikes have you in your store, when you have recorded only single outgoing transaction? Zero? Minus one? There seems something missing from your records, initial balance or similar transaction.

Comment: The thing is the user can create the number on the fly, so he can assign a number for outgoing transaction which is not even in his shop. But at the time his customer return thats item number that number should be available in the shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Number, 
       case when sum(quantity) >= 0 then 1 else 0 end
  from Table
group by Number
```

I think this solves your problem, this gives a list of numbers and 0 if they are not available and 1 if they are available

if you want only those that are available:

```
    select Number
      from Table
  group by Number
    having sum(quantity) >= 0
```

However, the problem is that given your description, this probably would work. As in case, where first S1 has an incomming transaction (1) and then an outgoing (-1), it would be considered to be available.

So i am not sure a SUM approach is workable in your case. The issue is that your requirements are not really clear.

If your example would be:

```
ID                                               Number         Quantity
45F39260-C646-4CDF-8FC9-E8A2C4B93B9D                S1           1  
F5B033A4-0294-4069-A4D4-9DDBD7D1915D                S2          -1
B94CDB62-9B8B-4C8A-983C-BD896181FEEA                S3           1
98F39260-C646-4CDF-8FC9-E9A2C4B93CH7                S1          -1
```

would S1 be considered available? If yes, my approach (with >=) works.

If not, then this problem cannot be solved by SUM but has has to check the last Quantity change. Either you need a datetime/rowversion field of when it happend and do a `select top 1 ..... order by ....` to get available numbers. However if you don't have a datetime/rowversion field, then what you want to do is imposible as there is no order in the data as by look of it, your ID is a GUID, not Sequential guid....

Ok, so this should do the trick:

```
     select Number
       from YourTable as prim
   group by Number
        having sum(quantity) >= case when (select top 1 quantity 
                                             from #test as sec
                                            where sec.number = prim.number
                                         order by dt desc) > 0 then 0
                                     else 1 end
```

PS
Honestly, thats a mess. Why not go with a trigger and Availability table?
In case of lots and lots and lots of transaction, your current solution with sum etc would get slower and slower and be a mess.

Comment: This will not solve the problem , as you can see that s1 first has an outgoing transaction with negative quantity and then it has an incomming transaction so it should be available.

Comment: Yes there is datetime column, but again if the sequence is incomming first and then outgoing then SUM works fine. But if the sequence is outgoing first and then incomming the SUM result wouldnt be able to differentiate if it the number s1 should be available or not-available.

Comment: Then why not use the datetime column to simply get the most recent instance of a transaction for each number, and use that to decide if it's available or not. `SUM` shouldn't come into this at all!?

Comment: Sorry that would also not work becasue a number s1 can have two incomming transactions and one outgoing  transaction .

Comment: So if the sum of the `Quantity` values is 0 then the number is available if the last transaction was incoming, but unavailable if the last transaction was outgoing. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it will be available if the sum of the Quantity values is 0 and also the last transaction was incoming. But on the other hand if the last transaction was outgoing then we need to relly on sum and see if its greater than ZERO.